# How to set textbox MaximumSize and MinimumSize application wide for WinForm C#

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am new to Winform C#.

I want to set the TextBox or TextEdit Property Maximum Size and Minimum Size Width application wide. how can I set this?

Comment: What do you mean by **application wide**?

Comment: You'll never get very far with Winforms if you don't use inheritance.  Just derive your own class from TextBox and set your preferred property values in the constructor.  Use the new control (added to the top of the toolbox after you compile) consistently in all your UI designs and you got what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion is understood. But I was hoping to to have some possibilities in existing TextEdit.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `class` which inherits from `TextBox`, implement your settings into the constructor, like this:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox {
    public MyTextBox() : base {
        //Set your properties as you like
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Hans said, You can extend the existing in-place editors and then you can easily use these custom control in any application.

Just you need to create a separate project and create classes which inherits existing DevExpres controls. for your requirement, you can use the `TextEdit` class inherited to some `TextEditEx:TextEdit`.

**From:** [Custom Editors](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4716)
Consider this simple example for creating a custom editor (CustomEdit). It represents the TextEdit class descendant. The new repository item class is RepositoryItemCustomEdit. It introduces a new property (UseDefaultMode) for illustration purposes.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Registrator;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Drawing;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.ViewInfo;
using DevExpress.Accessibility;

namespace DevExpress.CustomEditors {

    //The attribute that points to the registration method 
    [UserRepositoryItem("RegisterCustomEdit")]
    public class RepositoryItemCustomEdit : RepositoryItemTextEdit {

        //The static constructor that calls the registration method 
        static RepositoryItemCustomEdit() { RegisterCustomEdit(); }

        //Initialize new properties 
        public RepositoryItemCustomEdit() {            
            useDefaultMode = true;
        }

        //The unique name for the custom editor 
        public const string CustomEditName = "CustomEdit";

        //Return the unique name 
        public override string EditorTypeName { get { return CustomEditName; } }

        //Register the editor 
        public static void RegisterCustomEdit() {
            //Icon representing the editor within a container editor's Designer 
            Image img = null;
            try {
                img = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().
                  GetManifestResourceStream("DevExpress.CustomEditors.CustomEdit.bmp"));
            }
            catch {
            }
            EditorRegistrationInfo.Default.Editors.Add(new EditorClassInfo(CustomEditName, 
              typeof(CustomEdit), typeof(RepositoryItemCustomEdit), 
              typeof(TextEditViewInfo), new TextEditPainter(), true, img, typeof(TextEditAccessible)));
        }

        //A custom property 
        private bool useDefaultMode;

        public bool UseDefaultMode {
            get { return useDefaultMode; }
            set {
                if(useDefaultMode != value) {
                    useDefaultMode = value;                        
                    OnPropertiesChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        //Override the Assign method 
        public override void Assign(RepositoryItem item) {
            BeginUpdate(); 
            try {
                base.Assign(item);
                RepositoryItemCustomEdit source = item as RepositoryItemCustomEdit;
                if(source == null) return;
                useDefaultMode = source.UseDefaultMode;
            }
            finally {
                EndUpdate();
            }
        }
    }

    [ToolboxItem(true)]
    public class CustomEdit : TextEdit {

        //The static constructor that calls the registration method 
        static CustomEdit() { RepositoryItemCustomEdit.RegisterCustomEdit(); }

        //Initialize the new instance 
        public CustomEdit() {
            //... 
        }

        //Return the unique name 
        public override string EditorTypeName { get { return 
            RepositoryItemCustomEdit.CustomEditName; } }

        //Override the Properties property 
        //Simply type-cast the object to the custom repository item type 
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public new RepositoryItemCustomEdit Properties {
            get { return base.Properties as RepositoryItemCustomEdit; }
        }

    }
}
```

Refere these DevExpress documenation links for detailed information:
[How To Extend DevExpress Controls](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q346699)
[How to use a custom control in inplace mode in DevExpress containers](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A128)
[Inherited TextEdit - "Properties-Properties" are fixed after set within the contructor](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q313080)
[How to create a transparent TextEdit](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3225)